# Prove the sequence does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For each positive integer $k$ let $a_{2^k} = 1$ and for every $n$ that is not a power of $2$, let $a_n = 0$. Prove directly from the definition of convergence that the sequence $(a_n)$ does not converge.

**My attempt:**

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to some limit $L$. According to the definition of convergence, for every positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, the absolute difference $|a_n - L|$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

Consider $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. There exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|a_n - L| < \frac{1}{2}$.

Let $2^k > N$ be a power of $2$ and $m > N$ be a positive integer that is not a power of $2$. Consider the values of $a_{2^k}$ and $a_m$:

For $a_{2^k}$, we have $|a_{2^k} - L| = |1 - L| < \frac{1}{2}$.

For $a_m$, we have $|a_m - L| = |0 - L| = |L| < \frac{1}{2}$.

Now, apply the triangle inequality: $|A + B| \leq |A| + |B|$. Let $A = a_{2^k} - L$ and $B = L - a_m$.

$$|(a_{2^k}-L)+(L-a_m)|\leq|a_{2^k}-L|+|L-a_m|$$
$$|a_{2^k}-a_m|\leq|1-L|+|L|<\frac12+\frac12=1$$

However, we know that $a_{2^k} = 1$ and $a_m = 0$, so $|a_{2^k} - a_m| = 1$. This contradicts the inequality above.

Therefore, the assumption that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges is false. The sequence does not converge according to the given definition.

What is wrong in my proof?

Comment: for the second case consider any n which is not equal to $2^k$. What can you say about $|1-a_n|$, Why does such an n exist for every N?

Comment: I think you are assuming that the limit is unique and that $2^n\to\infty$. If you are allowed to it, I find your proof fine.

Comment: The choice of $\varepsilon = \frac 1 2$ is great, but I don't understand how you immediately conclude "So $L$ is either 0 or 1." ?

Comment: @watertrainer Why are we considering any $n$ which is not equal to $2^k$ in regard with only $L=1$, not $L=0$ as well? For $L=1$, it is $1<1/2$ which is false; and for $L=0$ we get $0<1/2$ which is true?

Comment: For you second case you should consider a *NON* power of two $\ge N$.  Then $|a_{non power of two} -1| = |0-1| = 1$ which is not less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Stef I updated my question.

Comment: @Stef has a point.  We can't assume we can guess the value of $L$ but *if* an $L$ exist it and we have $m, 2^k > N; m$ not a power of $2$ the we must have $|a_{2^k} - L| < \frac 12$ and $|a_m - L |< \frac 12$.  Is there any such $L$?

Comment: @Berlin And my comment still stands :-p I don't think you should guess the value of L. If you know about the so-called "triangular inequality" then you can conclude almost directly from fleablood's comment that the sequence cannot converge.

Comment: "Let's choose n=2k for some k such that 2k>N. Since 2k is a power of 2, L is either 0 or 1."  No.  That does not follow at all.  What *does* follow is that since $a_{2^k} =1$ we have $|1 -L| < \frac 12$ so $-\frac 12 < 1-L < \frac 12$ so $\frac 12 < L < 1\frac 12$.  For all we know, at this point, $L$ could be $0.6$ or $1.25436$.

Comment: You seem to be reluctant to consider cases where $m > N$ but $m$ is *not* a power of $2$.  Why are you not considering those?

Comment: @fleablood Oh ok, I will try this approach, but how exactly do I make it work? Edit: How do I apply the triangle inequality in this case?

Comment: First.  You need to throw away the idea that we should consider the values of $L$ by guessing.  WE DO NOT HAVE ANY IDEA WHAT L IS!  $L$ *might* turn out to be $27$bazillion for all we know.  BUT.  If the sequence converges, the for $\epsilon = \frac 12$ there an $N$ and an $L$ where $|a_n - L| < \frac 12$ for all $n > N$.  Consider $2^k>N$ and a $m> N$ where $m$ is not a power of $2$.  Then we must have $|a_2k -L| = |1-L| < \epsilon$ !!!AND!!! we must have $|a_m-L|=|0-L|=|L|< \epsilon$.  Show that that is impossible.

Comment: Triangle inequality is $|A + B| \le |A| + |B|$.  Let $A = a_{2^k-1} - L$ and let $B = L - a_m$.

Comment: I tried to update it, don't know if it's any good.

Comment: It's good now.  But what I want to know is how does it feel in you gut.  It should *feel* right.  ... Basically, the idea is that know matter how how we go we will always have some terms that equal to $1$ and we will always have some terms that are equal to $0$.  If a convergent limit existed it would have to be as close as we like to *both* $0$ and $1$ and that's impossible.  That *argument* should be convincing.  All the proof is doing is formalizing that concept.  If you "don't know if it's any good" I suggest you sit a while and ... well, meditate, I guess.

Comment: If the triangle inequality doesn't *feel* good then I wouldn't use it.  To me: "If it converges then for every $\epsilon>0$ we'd have an $L$ and an $N$ so that $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ for all $n>N$.  If $n = 2^k >N$ then $|a_n-L|=|1-L|< \epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon < L < 1+\epsilon$.  But if $n>N$ is not a power of $2$ then $|a_n-L|=|0-L|=|L|< \epsilon$ so $-\epsilon < L<\epsilon$.  So we must have both $-\epsilon < L <\epsilon$ and $1-\epsilon < 1<1+\epsilon$ and that is not possible for $\epsilon\le \frac 12$ so it can't be true for all $\epsilon$"  feels *very* right.

Comment: @fleablood I just revisited this question, out of curiosity, what are other possible ways to prove this without the triangle inequality?

Comment: I described one in my comment.  I didn't use the triangle inequality anywhere.  I just figued:  "We can't have a number that is infinitely close to *both* $1$ and $0$".  No single number can get closer than $\frac 12$ to both of them.  ANd to prove that.  If $0< \epsilon < \frac 12$ and $|1-L|< \epsilon$ *AND* $|0-L|< \epsilon$ then $-\epsilon < L < \epsilon < 1-\epsilon < L < 1+\epsilon$.  So $L < L$ which is a contradiction.  *NOWHERE* did I use the triangle inequality.

Comment: I must have skipped that. Thanks!